# how to check if list contains lists recursively

Tags: rcpp

I have a function in R that recursively builds a list of lists of varying depth. The output `node` may be be

```
node<-list(right=(0))
```

or

```
node<-list(right=list(right=0))
```

In Rcpp I would like to build a recursively deconstruct the list and return the integer member, 0 in this case.

My problem is checking if `node` has a named member `right`

```
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction(
'
int predict(List node){
   if(node["right"]){
     return predict(node["right"]);
   }
   else{
     return node;
   }
 }
}
'
)
```

I've looked at [Dynamic Wrapping](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/rcpp-wrap-and-recurse/) to check type and use switch/case, but it doesn't seem to like named lists.

Comment: Dynamic wrapping definitely likes lists... Did you specify `VECSXP`? Only the `INTSXP` and `REALSXP` are valid cases in that example. Furthermore, you need to add some _intermediary_ steps here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to check for existence of a named value using a subset, e.g. `if(node["right"])`, will trigger the following error:

```
Error in predict_bad(node) : Not compatible with requested type: [type=list; target=logical].
```

To search a `List` or `*Vector` for a named element, use [`.containsElementNamed("name")`](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/2d4eb219bdff6bb4675e46bf8ea73c7fe31b8fdf/inst/include/Rcpp/vector/Vector.h#L584) member function.

For example, we have:

```
#include<Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List predict_list(Rcpp::List node){

    // Check if name is present
    if(node.containsElementNamed("right")) {
        return predict_list(node["right"]);
    }

    return node;
}
```

Notice, here we are returning an `Rcpp::List`, e.g.

```
node1 = list(right = list(right = 0))  
predict_list(node1)
# [[1]]
# [1] 0
```

To obtain only an integer, we must first **subset** the list and **cast** to the appropriate type. The second component, if we are tricky enough, we can allow Rcpp automagic to handle the conversion. (Thanks to Qiang for revealing the prior answer does *not* have to be positionally limited.)

```
#include<Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int predict_node_val(Rcpp::List node) {

    // Check if name is present
    if(node.containsElementNamed("right")) {

        // Check if element isn't a list.
        switch(TYPEOF(node["right"])) {
        case REALSXP:
        case INTSXP:
            return node["right"];
        default: // Keep going down the tree
            return predict_node_val(node["right"]);
        }

    }

    // Quiet compiler by providing a final output case
    return -1;
}
```

Output:

```
node1 = list(right = list(right = 0))  
node2 = list(right = 0)  
predict_node_val(node1)
# [1] 0
predict_node_val(node2)
# [1] 0
```

There are a few assumptions made above... The first is we will *always* have a list architecture based on typing. The second is the value we want to retrieve is always listed as `"right"`. The third

Answer (score 1):

You can just get the names and check if there is an element `right`.

The following code should work:

```
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction(
  '
  int predict(List node) {
    std::vector<std::string> list_names = node.names();
    if (std::find(list_names.begin(), list_names.end(), "right") != list_names.end()) {
      if (TYPEOF(node["right"]) == REALSXP) {
        return node["right"];
      } else {
        return predict(node["right"]);
      }
    } else {
      return -1;
    }
  }
  '
)
```

The results

```
> node<-list(right=(0))
> predict(node)
[1] 0
> node<-list(right=list(right=0))
> predict(node)
[1] 0
```